Groovy ClassCastException
I hava a code:
try {
    Long id = p.id as Long
    ...
} catch (all){
    log.warn "Class p.id:${p.id.class} p.class:${p.class} '${p.id}' ${p}", all
}

p is an instance of Grails entity and id is Long
Periodically, less then 1% calls it fails with a error
Long id = p.id as Long line with the error
27/06 18:00:54.227 WARN xx.xx.LinksTagLib - Class p.id:class java.lang.Long p.class:class x.xx.elements.Person '58858' Person{id=58858}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@4203c306
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor449.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1956)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1150)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3843)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1162)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:329)
        at xx.xxx.LinksTagLib$_closure13.doCall(LinksTagLib.groovy:326)

How that possible? And how to fix it?
Update
Long b = 100
if (b == p.id){
...

Also fails with ClassCastException in compareason

java 11
groovy 3.0.11


Line 326 is the first fine of the try from your code snippet? Is p something more than just a dumb POJO?  E.g. is it under hibernates control?  Is this Grails by any chance?  What kind of closure is the try in?  What is LinkTagLib used for (assuming this is Grails, is it used to do work at the final stages of a request doing something inside a template)?

smells like a hibernate proxy problem to me

@cfrick  as I wrote, p is an instance of entity. Taglib used on gsp rendering.  P instances also cached by hibernate L2 cache. I agree with injecterr --- looks like a proxy/cache problem. But how to solve it?

My first thought would be GrailsHibernateUtil.unwrapIfProxy() if this is a proxy class.  I've usually only observed that in instances of a multi-tiered domain inheritance hierarchy, but could easily happen in other situations.
